# What is the format for the dependency version to install github pages and jekyll?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, bundler, github-pages

I was following [the github instructions for jekyll and github](https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-jekyll#creating-your-site). At step 8 & 9 it says:

> 8) Open the Gemfile that was created and follow the instructions in the
>   Gemfile's comments to use GitHub Pages.
>
> ```
> # uncomment the line below. To upgrade, run `bundle update github-pages`.
> gem "github-pages", group: :jekyll_plugins
> ```
>
> 9) Update the gem "github-pages" line so that the line looks like this, replacing VERSION with the current dependency version for
>   github-pages. For more information, see "Dependency versions" on the
>   GitHub Pages site.
>
> `gem "github-pages", "~> VERSION", group: :jekyll_plugins`

but I don't understand what goes in `VERSION`

I tried the following:

```
# gem "github-pages", "~> jekyll 3.8.5", group: :jekyll_plugins
#gem "github-pages", "~> 3.8.5", group: :jekyll_plugins
```

but they all result in errors. However, its obvious that the errors don't matter because I don't know what is suppose to go in `Version`. Whats supposed to go in version `VERSION`?

---

related error:

- https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-to-install-github-pages-with-jekyll/3510

Comment: "_but they all result in errors_" What errors? Please take a moment to read both https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, then come back and update this question and the one you opened earlier about the same issue.

Comment: @anothermh perhaps the title is not suggestive enough to you understand my questions. So I kindly emphasized what my question is about since perhaps people skip the title of the question.

Comment: seems like the last thing I need to have this work is this `Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll-feed":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll-feed (~> 0.12)

    github-pages (= 202) was resolved to 202, which depends on
      jekyll-feed (= 0.11.0)` just in case someone knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions for the github-pages gem are different than for the Jekyll gem.

To look up a gem's versions, use RubyGems.org.

Here are the versions for github-pages: https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages

The latest version is 202, so you'd put:

```
gem "github-pages", "202"
```

With each new release (you can watch [the github/pages-gem repo for releases](https://github.com/github/pages-gem) if you want to be notified when new ones are released), just replace the `"202"` with the new version in quotes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: seems like the last thing I need to have this work is this `Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll-feed":
  In Gemfile:
    jekyll-feed (~> 0.12)

    github-pages (= 202) was resolved to 202, which depends on
      jekyll-feed (= 0.11.0)` just in case you know.